# How to design a sub-stream object in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I'm designing an API in Python. The API has two versions, different versions have some difference for each API.

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, username, password, version):
        pass


class ClientV2:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        pass

    def jobs():
        pass

    def model():
        # V3 doesn't have this method.
        pass

class ClientV3:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        pass

    def jobs():
        # the logic is different from V2
        pass
```

What I'm looking for is like:

```
client = Client('user', 'passwd', 3)
# if the version = 3, then the client object will be ClientV3 actually.

# if the version = 2, then the client object will be ClientV2 actually.
```

Is there any typical Object-Oriented Design for this in Python?

Appreciate for any suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of **Factory Pattern** in this case. One such working example:

NOTE: if you are using python2 make sure all classes mentioned below inherited from `object` class

```
class Client:
    def __new__(cls, username, password, version):
        if version == 2:
            return ClientV2(username, password)
        elif version == 3:
            return ClientV3(username, password)

        raise Exception("version={0} not supported".format(version))

class ClientV2:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        pass

    def jobs(self):
        pass


class ClientV3:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        pass

    def jobs(self):
        # the logic is different from V2
        pass
```

and then you can use it in the following way:

```
client = Client('user', 'passwd', 3)
# if the version = 3, then the client object will be ClientV3 actually.

# if the version = 2, then the client object will be ClientV2 actually.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understood it correctly but you can try something:

Create a map:

```
VERSION_MAP = {version_no: Class_Ref}
```

and inside your client class:

```
_client = VERSION_MAP[version_no](**kwargs)
access any method using _client.method
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, is the Client exposed?  can I access like from xx import Client;c=Client('user','pass', version=3)

Comment: You need to have some interface to get the actual client. That can be some function or a client class.